# How to define a incomplete metric on $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $\mathbb{S}^1=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ \|x\|_2=1\}$.

My question is: Is it possible to define a incomplete metric on $\mathbb{S}^1$, i.e. a metric such that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is not complete.

Thank you.

Comment: Any metric, or should it induce the standard topology?

Comment: Any metric @DanielFischer

Comment: Then take any bijection with an incomplete metric space of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. For example $[0,\,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f \colon (0,1) \to \mathbb S^1$ be a bijection. Define $d(x,y) = |f^{-1}(x) - f^{-1}(y)|$, then $f$ is an isometry, hence $(\mathbb S^1, d)$ is not complete.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to induce the standard topology, no, you can't. It is compact, and therefore, any metric inducing it will be complete (and totally bounded).